# WP get page by title function with array values

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use WP function `get_page_by_title` for getting page ID by its title, and using this code,

```
$page = get_page_by_title("page name" 'OBJECT', 'post_type');
```

It works fine if we pass a single page name, but I need to get id's from multiple pages for instance, I've an array (`$tenders`) which holds the selected pages name and I need to pass similar as below

```
$page = get_page_by_title($tenders, 'OBJECT', 'post_type');
```

It doesn't work at all for some reason! I spent lot of time for suitable solution but in vain. Any quick fix for this issue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the ID's with **foreach loop.**

Let suppose you have an array of page titles.

```
$tenders = array( "page One", "Page Two", "Page Three" );

foreach ( $tenders as $tender ) {
  $page = get_page_by_title( $tender, 'OBJECT', 'post_type' );
  // see the ID
  echo $page;
}
```

Comment: That was simple and bull's eye solution. Thanks